# What type of graph can best show the correlation between 'Fare' (price) and "Survival" (Titanic)?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm playing around with Seaborn and Matplotlib and I trying to find the best type of graph to show the correlation between fare values and chance of survival from the titanic dataset.

The Titanic fare column has a lot of different values  ranging from 1 to 500 and some of the values are repeated often.

Here is a sample of value_counts:

```
titanic.fare.value_counts()

8.0500     43
13.0000    42
7.8958     38
7.7500     34
26.0000    31
10.5000    24
7.9250     18
7.7750     16
0.0000     15
7.2292     15
26.5500    15
8.6625     13
7.8542     13
7.2500     13
7.2250     12
16.1000     9
9.5000      9
15.5000     8
24.1500     8
14.5000     7
7.0500      7
52.0000     7
31.2750     7
56.4958     7
69.5500     7
14.4542     7
30.0000     6
39.6875     6
46.9000     6
21.0000     6
 .....
91.0792     2
106.4250    2
164.8667    2
```

Survival column on the other hand has only two values :

```
>>> titanic.survived.head(10)
271    1
597    0
302    0
633    0
277    0
413    0
674    0
263    0
466    0
```

A histogram would only show the frequency of fares in certain ranges.
For a scatter plot I would need  two variables; having "survived" which has only two values would make for a strange variable.

Is there a way to show the rise of survivability as fare increases clearly through a line graph?

I know there is a correlation as If I sort fare values in ascending order (000-500).
Then  do:

```
>>> titanic.head(50).survived.sum()
  5

>>>titanic.tail(50).survived.sum()

37
```

I see a correlation.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this should work...  titanic.groupby([tinanic.fare // 10]).survived.mean().reset_index().plot.scatter(0, 1)

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a logistic regression

Comment: @PiRSquared,Thanks, it seems to be showing the rise.  What's the reasoning behind using //10?

Comment: @mwaskom --  Thanks I will take a look at it and see what I come up with.

Comment: @moondra // is floor division. It's a convenient way to group continuous data. 10 was arbitrary. Feel free to experiment with it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah I played around with it for a bit and figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to show the correlation between the fare values and the chance of survival:

First, I created a new column `Fare Groups`, converting fare values to groups of fare ranges, using [cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html).

```
df['Fare Groups'] = pd.cut(df.Fare, [0,50,100,150,200,550])
```

Next, I created a [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```
piv_fare = df.pivot_table(index='Fare Groups', columns='Survived', values = 'Fare', aggfunc='count')
```

Output:

```
Survived     0   1
Fare Groups         
(0, 50]     484 232
(50, 100]   37  70
(100, 150]  5   19
(150, 200]  3   6
(200, 550]  6   14
```

Plot:

```
piv_fare.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

It seems, those who had the cheapest tickets (0 to 50) had the lowest chance of survival. In fact, (0 to 50) is the only fare range where the chance to die is higher than the chance to survive. Not just higher, but significantly higher.